# RTL support for vector drawable for below API 19

Tags: android, right-to-left, android-vectordrawable

I have a `vector` drawable.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:autoMirrored="true"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#65666a"
        android:pathData="M8.59,16.34l4.58,-4.59 -4.58,-4.59L10,5.75l6,6 -6,6z" />
</vector>
```

I have added `android:autoMirrored="true"` attribute to support RTL, but it is only used in API 19 and higher. But my minimum API level is API 17. How can I add backward comparability? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, instead of using `autoMirrored`, use this workaround to do your own "automirror".

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <group
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:scaleX="@dimen/rtl_automirror_scale">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#65666a"
            android:pathData="M8.59,16.34l4.58,-4.59 -4.58,-4.59L10,5.75l6,6 -6,6z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

Here I've deleted the autoMirror attribute and instead wrapped the vector path in a `<group>` tag with a `pivotX` point of 12 (ie. the middle of the drawable) and a `scaleX` pointing to a Dimen resource.

In your normal values folder you would provide the resource as:

```
<resources>

    <item name="rtl_automirror_scale" format="float" type="dimen">1</item>

</resources>
```

A value of 1 for the scale means no change, just the normal drawable.

However you can then provide an alternate values resource for `RTL` devices in `values-ldrtl`:

```
<resources>

    <item name="rtl_automirror_scale" format="float" type="dimen">-1</item>

</resources>
```

A value of -1 means the `VectorDrawable` will be flipped horizontally for `RTL` devices.

Then whenever you have other `VectorDrawables` which need to be flipped, just wrap them in a group tag as above, pointing to the same dimen.

Comment: i got error
Error:Error: For input string: "@dimen/layout_direction_aware_scale"

Comment: @amorenew, I'm not sure about that error, but your comment did make me read this post again and see a problem. I used two different names for the dimen resource so have now corrected that!

Comment: You put one more / in `<group/>...</group>` by mistake

Comment: is it necessary to add pivotX attribute?

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery I would say so. Otherwise pivotX would default to zero and the result would be that the image would pivot around the left hand side rather than the centre. I think in many cases that means it wouldn't be visible at all as it's gone beyond the left hand side of the drawable's viewport, but if it can still be seen then it would have shifted position too, rather than just flipping the image in its original location.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work - I get this exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@dimen/rtl_automirror_scale"`

Answer (score 3):

in my imageview i added

```
android:scaleX="@integer/local_mirror_scale_x"
```

then in integers.xml in values

in english integers

```
<integer name="local_mirror_scale_x">1</integer>
```

in arabic integers

```
<integer name="local_mirror_scale_x">-1</integer>
```

Comment: Hi @amorenew i tried this but i got error  " Error:Error: For input string: "@integer/local_mirror_scale_x  " i don't know why

Comment: @ahmedShoeib try to clean and build may be your project not recognize the link to that id

Comment: still the issue exist after clean and build

Comment: I am not sure but try the same solution in a separate project may be a typo error or something else

Comment: What if was `TextView` instead of `ImageView`

Comment: for TextView you have to make it by code not xml or use png in drawable-ar folder